# r data.table: two questions about 'by' ((1)=.I and (2)='order by')

Tags: r, data.table

I have two questions about the 'by' in the package data.table.

1) How can one use `.I` together with it? For example, lets say that we have users who come into a shop at certain times of the day and I want a variable telling me ''the how much-th's time is it that we see this user?''... i.e.

```
> library(data.table)
> dt = data.table(visitorId = c(1,2,1,2,1), daytime=c(1,4,7,9,11))
> dt
       visitorId daytime
1:         1        1
2:         2        4
3:         1        7
4:         2        9
5:         1       11
```

the desired solution would produce

```
       visitorId daytime  howOftenHaveYouBeenHere
1:         1        1              1
2:         2        4              1
3:         1        7              2
4:         2        9              2
5:         1       11              3
```

Now I played around with the `.I` of data.table and nothing gave me what I wanted: The thing .I (:-) sorry, couldnt resist) would have expected to work is `dt = dt[, howOftenHaveYouBeenHere := .I, by=visitorId]` but this gives

```
       visitorId daytime  howOftenHaveYouBeenHere
1:         1        1              1
2:         2        4              1
3:         1        7              2
4:         2        9              2
5:         1       11              1 <---- not a 3 here!!!
```

I made it work using

```
dt = dt[, stupid := 1]
dt = dt[, session := cumsum(stupid), by=visitorId]; print(dt)
```

but it doesnt feel well to do it like this...

2) How to assure that data.table counts sessions by 'time', i.e. until now I did

a) order the table accordingly

b) execute 'by'statements

is that the right way or can one 'smuggle in' SQL's 'ORDER BY' somewhere?

For example: if we reverse the data table from above
`dt = data.table(visitorId = c(1,2,1,2,1), daytime=c(11,9,7,4,1))`
then

```
dt = dt[, stupid := 1]
dt = dt[, session := cumsum(stupid), by=visitorId]; print(dt)
```

does not give the desired result. We can fix it by doing it like so:

```
dt = data.table(visitorId = c(1,2,2,1,1), dayTime=c(11,9,4,7,1))
dt = dt[order(dayTime, decreasing=FALSE)]
dt = dt[, stupid := 1]
dt = dt[, howOftenHaveYouBeenHere := cumsum(stupid), by=visitorId]
```

but is there a 'correct' way of doing it? I.e. is it guaranteed that the order stays fixed while doing the by-statement?

Thanks :-)

FW

Comment: Sorry, was confused and caught in the middle of playing with your solution :-) Is it clear now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.I` is the counter within the whole table -- not by group. We need to construct a within-group counter:

```
dt[, seqobs := seq_along(.I), by=visitorId]
# or...
dt[, seqobs := seq_len(.N), by=visitorId]
# or...
dt[, seqobs := 1:.N, by=visitorId]

#    visitorId daytime seqobs
# 1:         1       1      1
# 2:         2       4      1
# 3:         1       7      2
# 4:         2       9      2
# 5:         1      11      3
```

This is easier than initializing a column of ones and taking the cumulative sum.

---

The data would need to be sorted by `daytime` within each group for this to make sense. If it's not...

```
# example of an out-of-order table
dt2 <- dt[sample(.N)]

dt2[order(daytime), seqobs := seq(.N), by=visitorId]
```

By the way, if you want to change the order of a data.table, use the `setorder` function.

(In the next version of the data.table package, 1.9.8, there will be a small shortcut `dt[, seqobs := rowidv(visitorId)]`. I am making this note so I can update the answer later.)